is there any function to get document more than 5000 in spfx
I want filter data from list and then filter only 5000 data are coming but there is more than 50000 documents.
Current code:
import * as React from "react"; import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; // import DataTable from "react-data-table-component"; import { IAllPublishDocumentProps } from "./IAllPublishDocumentProps"; import { useEffect, useState } from "react"; // import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next"; import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"; import "react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.css"; // import filterFactory, { textFilter } from "react-bootstrap-table2-filter"; // import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator"; import "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-paginator.min.css"; import "react-bootstrap-table2-filter/dist/react-bootstrap-table2-filter.min.css"; // import CheckIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Check"; // import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

// -----------------Re-loader------------------- import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap"; import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, //   ISPHttpClientOptions, } from "@microsoft/sp-http";

export const PublishDoc = (props: IAllPublishDocumentProps) => { const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); const [PublishDocument, setPublishDocuments] = useState([]); const [itemId, setitemId] = useState<number[]>([]); const [alldata, setalldata] = useState([]); const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0); const [filterdata, setfilterdata] = useState({ OldTagId: "", DocID: "", DocumentName: "", DocumentType: "", Created: "", AuthorName: "", RevisionNo: "", DocName: "", }); console.log(currentPage); console.log(itemId); console.log(alldata); console.log(PublishDocument); const pageSize = itemId.length + 10; // const handlePrevPageClick = async (pageNumber: number) => { console.log(pageNumber); if (pageNumber < 1) { alert("you are already in first page"); } else { if (pageNumber === 1) { fetchData(); } else { let prevPage = currentPage - 1; console.log(prevPage);

    let posId = (prevPage - 1) * 9 - 9;
    console.log(posId);
    let Id = itemId[posId];
    console.log(Id);
    let url2 = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27TestPerformance%27)/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d${Id}&=&%24top=10`;
    let nextdata = await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
      url2,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
          "odata-version": "",
        },
      }
    );
    const nextdatajson = await nextdata.json();
    console.log(nextdatajson);
    const newData = nextdatajson.value.map((item: any) => ({
      ID: item.ID,
      GuidData: item.RUID,
      OrignalID: item.OrignalID,
      OLDTagID: item.OldTagId,
      DocumentID: item.DocID,
      DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
      DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
      SubmissionDate: item.Created,
      RequestedBy: item.AuthorName,
      Version: item.RevisionNo,
      PublishDocument: item.DocName,
      PublishDocument2:
        props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
        "/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" +
        encodeURIComponent(item.DocName),
    }));
    setCurrentPage(prevPage);
     setPublishDocuments(newData);
    setIsLoading(false);
   
  }
}

}; const handleNextPageClick = async () => { console.log(currentPage); console.log(itemId); let nextPage = currentPage + 1; console.log(nextPage);

let posId = (nextPage - 1) * 9;
console.log(posId);
let Id = itemId[posId];
console.log(Id);
let url2 = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27TestPerformance%27)/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d${Id}&=&%24top=10`;
let nextdata = await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
  url2,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
  {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
      "odata-version": "",
    },
  }
);
const nextdatajson = await nextdata.json();
console.log(nextdatajson);
const newData = nextdatajson.value.map((item: any) => ({
  ID: item.ID,
  GuidData: item.RUID,
  OrignalID: item.OrignalID,
  OLDTagID: item.OldTagId,
  DocumentID: item.DocID,
  DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
  DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
  SubmissionDate: item.Created,
  RequestedBy: item.AuthorName,
  Version: item.RevisionNo,
  PublishDocument: item.DocName,
  PublishDocument2:
    props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
    "/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" +
    encodeURIComponent(item.DocName),
}));
//   let url2 = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestPerformance')/items?$top=10&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=${newData[9].ID}`;
setCurrentPage(nextPage);
for (let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
  const newItemId = newData[i].ID;

  if (itemId.indexOf(newItemId) === -1) {
    setitemId((prevState) => [...prevState, newItemId]);
  }
}
setPublishDocuments(newData);
setIsLoading(false);
// setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

}; const fetchData = async () => { setIsLoading(true); try { const url = ${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestPerformance')/items?&$top=10;

  const response: SPHttpClientResponse =
    await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
      url,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
          "odata-version": "",
        },
      }
    );
  const responsejson = await response.json();
  console.log(responsejson);

  const newData = responsejson.value.map((item: any) => ({
    ID: item.ID,
    GuidData: item.RUID,
    OrignalID: item.OrignalID,
    OLDTagID: item.OldTagId,
    DocID: item.DocID,
    DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
    DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
    Created: item.Created,
    AuthorName: item.AuthorName,
    RevisionNo: item.RevisionNo,
    DocName:
      props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
      "/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" +
      encodeURIComponent(item.EncodedAbsUrl),
  }));


  setCurrentPage(1);
  for (let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    const newItemId = newData[i].ID;

    if (itemId.indexOf(newItemId) === -1) {
      setitemId((prevState) => [...prevState, newItemId]);
    }
  }
  setPublishDocuments(newData);
  setIsLoading(false);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  setIsLoading(false);
}

};

const filterData = async () => { setIsLoading(true); try { let filterUrl = ${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestPerformance')/items?$top=40000&$filter=substringof('${filterdata.DocumentType}',DocumentType);

  const response: SPHttpClientResponse =
    await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
      filterUrl,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
          "odata-version": "",
        },
      }
    );

  const filteredData = await response.json();
  console.log(filteredData.value);
  // setalldata(filteredData.value);

  const newData = filteredData.value.map((item: any) => ({
    ID: item.ID,
    GuidData: item.RUID,
    OrignalID: item.OrignalID,
    OLDTagID: item.OldTagId,
    DocID: item.DocID,
    DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
    DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
    Created: item.Created,
    AuthorName: item.AuthorName,
    RevisionNo: item.RevisionNo,
    DocName:
      props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
      "/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" +
      encodeURIComponent(item.EncodedAbsUrl),
  }));

  setPublishDocuments(newData);
  setalldata(newData);
  setIsLoading(false);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error filtering data:", error);
  setIsLoading(false);
}

}; const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => { let name = event.target.name; let value = event.target.value;

// Apply filtering based on the selected field and value
const filteredData = alldata.filter((data: any) => {
  // Handle filtering based on different fields
  if (name === "DocID") {
    return data["DocID"] === value;
  } else if (name === "DocumentName") {
    return data["DocumentName"] === value;
  } else if (name === "Created") {
    return data["Created"] === value;
  } else if (name === "AuthorName") {
    return data["AuthorName"] === value;
  } else if (name === "RevisionNo") {
    return data["RevisionNo"] === value;
  } else if (name === "DocName") {
    return data["DocName"] === value;
  }
  // Return true by default if no filtering criteria match
  return true;
});

// Update the PublishDocument state with the filtered data
setPublishDocuments(filteredData);
setalldata(filteredData);

// Update the filterdata state with the selected value
setfilterdata((prevFilterData) => ({
  ...prevFilterData,
  [name]: value,
}));

};

const handleDocumentType = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => { console.log(event.target); const { name, value } = event.target; setfilterdata((prevFilterData) => ({ ...prevFilterData, [name]: value, })); }; console.log(filterdata); const ClearData = () => { setfilterdata({ OldTagId: "", DocID: "", DocumentName: "", DocumentType: "", Created: "", AuthorName: "", RevisionNo: "", DocName: "", }); setalldata([]); fetchData(); }; useEffect(() => { fetchData(); // getAllItems(); }, []);



Try using PnPjs getAll() method.
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#get-all-items

Using the items collection's getAll method you can get
all of the items in a list regardless of the size of the list. Only the odata operations top, select, and
filter are supported.

